# How to make a polygon centered at {0,0} with scaled dimensions?

Tags: coordinate

I am making a customized plot marker `mk2` (a black star) with `Polygon`. Another marker `mk1` (a red circle) I made with `Circle` is properly centered. However, I could not figure out how to make `mk2` centered at `{0,0}` so I can use it later to mark properly some data points without shifting. Here is the code:

```
mk1 = {AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.02]]} // 
  Graphics
l = 1/50; k = 1/150;
mk2 = Polygon[
   Scaled /@ {{l, 0}, {k, k}, {0, l}, {-k, k}, {-l, 
       0}, {-k, -k}, {0, -l}, {k, -k}}] // Graphics
Show[mk2, mk1, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The coordinates of `mk2` need to be given in `Scaled` numbers. How can I make `mk2` also centered at `{0,0}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Scaled[offset, location]` instead:

```
mk1 = Graphics[
    {AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Red, Circle[{0,0}, Scaled[0.02]]}
];
l = 1/50; k = 1/150;
mk2 = Graphics[
    Polygon[Scaled[#,{0,0}]&/@{{l,0},{k,k},{0,l},{-k,k},{-l,0},{-k,-k},{0,-l},{k,-k}}],
    Axes->True
];
Show[mk2,mk1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to  `Scale` the polygon with ordinary coordinates:

```
s = .02;
mk1 = Graphics@ {AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[s]]};
l = 1; k = 1/3; 
mk2 = Graphics @ 
    Scale[Polygon[{{l, 0}, {k, k}, {0, l}, {-k, k}, {-l,  0}, {-k, -k}, {0, -l}, {k, -k}}], 
     2 s];
Show[mk2, mk1, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]